# Can't upgrade macports under Big Sur!

Tags: install, xcode, macports, big-sur

I just upgraded to big Sur and the macports upgrade instructions don't work.

I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: The macOS 11.0 SDK does not appear to be installed. Ports may not build correctly.
Warning: You can install it as part of the Xcode Command Line Tools package by running `xcode-select --install'.
```

But *I do have Xcode Command Line Tools installed*:

```
% xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
%
```

What's up?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turns out that the Big Sur's XCode command-line tools aren't good enough for MacPorts. You need to manually download Command Line Tools for Xcode 12.2 from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=command%20line%20tools

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me. Strangely, after that, Software Update updated the command-line tools yet again (to 12.2 and without breaking anything).

Comment: Yes, it did the same to me, also.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! I watched `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/` while installation. Before installation, there was no `MacOSX11.0.sdk/` and `MacOS.sdk` was a symlink to `MacOSX10.15.sdk`. After installation, `MacOS.sdk` links to the newly created `MacOSX11.0.sdk`.

Comment: Right after the installation from the apple developer site, `MacOSX11.0.sdk` is timestamped `Oct 20 05:39`. After Software Update, it is the time it is updated.

Comment: Thank you, I was thought have to wait for 2.6.5, but luckily see your answer.

Answer (score 2):

MacPorts typically uses different installers for different versions of macOS. Have you installed the [MacPorts for Big Sur](https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.6.4_1-11-BigSur.pkg), or are you trying to upgrade MacPorts with a `port` command?

Have you seen [this notice re updating MacPorts?](https://www.macports.org/news/):

```
% sudo port selfupdate
```

I don't run/haven't installed Big Sur, but I've used MacPorts for a while. MacPorts often issues a similar puzzling error after Catalina upgrades - it's puzzling until you learn what causes it. A *symptom* similar to the one you describe occurred after *in-version* and/or Xcode upgrades on Catalina (e.g. 10.15.5 to 10.15.6). The explanation, and the fix, are [described here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/ProblemHotlist#reinstall-clt).

Hopefully, one of these will get you back on track.

Comment: Thanks. I did download the new MacPorts installer. I've been using MacPorts since 2007. I find that it's frequently easier to just do a `rm -rf /opt/local` and reinstall from scratch...

Comment: @vy32: Yeah - sorry, I didn't see your answer when I started mine - got distracted & came back to it hours later. Glad to hear you got it working. MacPorts is fairly picky about the version of CLT. 2007 - you've been using it longer than I have  :)

Comment: Things change so fast, being an old-timer is not necessarily an advantage. Also, I could remain a novice user for years and years by stubbornly refusing to read the documentation! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it:

- I've upgraded developer-tools through system update. (If this doesn't works you can do it manually from here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=command%20line%20tools)
- Then I went to macports download page: https://www.macports.org/install.php and downloaded the Big Sur version.
- After installing Macports again (without uninstalling the current version) I've ran `sudo port selfupdate` and `sudo port upgrade outdated`.

Everything is working again.